# Cannot enlarge Vmware host windows

Tags: vmware

I have Fedora 17 installed on VMWare Fusion 3 on my Macbook Pro 2009. I run Fedora 17 in CLI mode and find I cannot enlarge the window size. The small terminal window size causes text to wrap and hard to read.  But when I try to size the window it doesn't let me.

How to resize host windows in VMWare fusion?

[image]

Comment: Isn't this expected behavior? I've never seen a terminal with different dimensions. Consider SSHing into the VMware client and using it as your terminal. There you can resize the window how you like it.

Comment: Additionally this might be more appropriate on SU

Comment: @KMC, I'm in agreement with MaxRied about migrating this to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).